# Nopcommerce - missing resources in localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, nopcommerce

I am trying to learn NopCommerce, and planning to use it for a project. I downloaded the source code of version 2.50. I compiled the code and completed db installation.

Now some of localization resources cannot be seen as resource values.

- For example, in administration there is a `Admin.Header.LoggedInAs`
  text next to logout.
- On datagrids (Telerik i think) on header and
  footer lines, there is
  `Admin.Telerik.GridLocalization.DisplayingItems`.
- On store homepage,
  there is a `News.MoreInfo` text after the news item.
- I have one item in shopping cart and there is `ShoppingCart.Mini.OneItemText` text on
  mini shopping cart.
- There is "Availability:
  `Products.Availability.InStock` text, next to every product that is is
  stock.

I double checked all of the Resource Keys thorough `Admin > Languages` datagrid, and made sure that these are on SQL Server database also.

How can i fix or debug it?

I checked views with breakpoints on `T["Admin.Header.LoggedInAs"]` and its Text property is `Admin.Header.LoggedInAs` for example.

It is strange that all or most of the resource values have `{0}` and of course used with `string.Format`

Comment: I realized that if i change case from "ShoppingCart.Mini.OneItemText" to "shoppingcart.mini.oneıtemtext", everything works fine. I am using regional and language settings as Turkey/Turkish. BTW, server is local. Is it only working with English regional settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out that the problem is caused by the collation of SQL Server db.

My local SQL Server's default collation is `Turkish_CI_AS`, so if i create a db from SQL Server Management Studio, it creates `Turkish_CI_AS` collation db by default.

I created a db with `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation, and now everything works fine.